# Orientdb 3.0 How to use map field for dynamic attributes without loosing existing data

Tags: orientdb

How   I am trying to use map to store multiple  key value properties. the problem I see is that it doesn't let me store existing data, it overrides  data everytime I tried to set a new property.

```
 Create VERTEX Person extends V;
CREATE CLASS Person EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Person.name STRING (MANDATORY TRUE, MIN 3, MAX 50);
Create VERTEX Person set name="test";
 update ( SELECT from Person where name="test") SET mapField=
 {"property1":mapField.property1+10};
```

set  property1 into map, and update it, works just fine.

```
update ( SELECT from Person where name="test") SET mapField=
{"property1":mapField.property1+30};
select from Person;
```

Set another property "property2", now I loose the property1.

```
update ( SELECT from Person where name="test") SET mapField=
{"property2":mapField.property2+10};
 select from Person;
```

is ther a way I can retain previous property and make this work still?

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
update ( SELECT from Person where name="test") 
SET mapField.property1 = mapField.property1 + 30;
```

In V 2.2 there was also an UPDATE PUT option, ie.

```
update ( SELECT from Person where name="test") 
PUT mapField = property1, eval('mapField.property1 + 30');
```

but it's not supported anymore (and it's definitely ugly)

Comment: Thanks  Luigi, this works fine with null value (initially?) or should I use coalesce function?